# How can i get and set APIs(getting in int value from server) in android from server? How to bind and implement this

Tags: java, android, json, api, android-asynctask

i am getting response from APIs Role id (in int value). how can i get and set this role id  in my android project so i can use this globally.

```
TextView  profile_fullName;
TextView profile_roleName;

int inspect=18;
int contract=19;

profile_fullName=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.profile_fullName);
profile_roleName=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.profile_role);
```

This is the response from APIs

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": {
    "UserName": "ABC",
    "ComanyName": "ABC XYZ COMPANY Ltd",
    "Email": "abc.xyz@gmail.com",
    "FullName": "ABC",
    "RoleName": "logged in as Engineer",
    "RoleId": 19
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the issue? You queried the API and got a response.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, The response is an`JSONObject`. so extract the response via `JSONObject`.

on your `onResponse()`

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        if (String.valueOf(response.get("success")).equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {   //this is just an additional validation
            JSONObject jsonObjectInner = new JSONObject(String.valueOf("message"));
            profile_fullName.setText(jsonObjectInner.get("FullName"));
            profile__roleName.setText(jsonObjectInner.get("RoleName"));

        }else{
         //add validation if success column is != true
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```